# What do these prefixes mean in Vim's explorer view

Tags: vim

In the quote you see Vim's file explorer view for some directory. Notice how all files have an `r` prefixed. I've also encountered this with `n`. What do those mean?

Whenever this happens, I'm having trouble opening files or directories (it simply doesn't work).

Maybe it is important to state that the directory is under SVN version control.

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v149)
"   <snip>
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec
" ============================================================================
r/../
r/./
r/Aussagenlogik_Grundlagen-Loesung.tex
r/Aussagenlogik_Grundlagen.tex
r/Klausur-Loesung.tex
r/Klausur.aux
r/Klausur.log
r/Klausur.out
r/Klausur.pdf
r/Klausur.tex
r/Klausur.tex.latexmain
r/Resolution-Loesung.tex
r/Resolution.tex
r/STRIPS-Formalisieren.tex
r/STRIPS-InitialState.tex
r/Suche.tex
r/Unifikation.tex
r/.NetrwMessage.swp
```

### Problematic path example

As requested in the comments. Note the `<snip_only alpha>` parts contained names with only ordinary ASCII characters `[a-zA-Z]` and no space or such.

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v149)
"   /home/thomas/workspace/ki-svn/proseminar-SS15/02-impulsvorträge
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,\~\=\*$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.info$,\.swp$,\.bak$,\~$
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec
" ============================================================================
e/../
e/./
e/totalslides/
e/<snip_only alpha>.pdf
e/<snip_only alpha>.pdf
e/<snip_only alpha>.pdf
e/<snip_only alpha>.pdf
e/<snip_only alpha>.pdf
e/<snip_only alpha>.pdf
e/<snip_only alpha>.pdf
```

Comment: Looks like a problem in the plugin; the filename isn't correctly cut out from the full globbed path. Do you have special (non-ASCII) characters inside the path? Try out the latest plugin version from [drchip's website](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#NETRW), and if the problem persists, contact the author.

Comment: I see that the directory's name has been snipped out, but I'd guess it has something unusual about the directory name that's causing retention of "r/" as Ingo said.  Please try reading :help netrw-debug.

Comment: @ziggystar : I suggest contacting netrw's maintainer.  The version of netrw you're using (v149) dates from Apr 2013; the latest netrw is v154e. Also may I note that when you're using accented characters in your directory names that the encoding that vim is using must be consistent with that used to produce the directory (or file) name.  So, what encoding is your filename in (latin1? utf-8? cp437? etc).  Did you use that same encoding when running vim + netrw?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments by Ingo and user21497 suggest, the effect is indeed caused by the occurrence of certain characters in the path.

It appears unrelated to versioning of the directory with Subversion.

This means it is a bug.

Comment: Would you please tell us what the path is, or at least the problematic characters?  The problem isn't likely to be fixed unless the maintainer knows about the problem.  Helpful: which liststyle are you using and what encoding are you using?